# How to track clipboard changes in the background using C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, clipboard

I need to process the contents of the clipboard in the background application.

How can I do this?

I need an event that will be called each time when the clipboard is changed. It does not matter from which the application is copying.

I know the function for reading and writing, such as `GetClipboardData()` and `SetClipboardData()`.

Got any ideas how to do this in C++?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Since Windows Vista, the right method is to use clipboard format listeners:

```
case WM_CREATE: 
  // ...
  AddClipboardFormatListener(hwnd);
  // ...
  break;

case WM_DESTROY: 
  // ...
  RemoveClipboardFormatListener(hwnd);
  // ...
  break;

case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
  // Clipboard content has changed
  break;
```

---

See [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents):

> There are three ways of monitoring changes to the clipboard. The oldest method is to create a clipboard viewer window. Windows 2000 added the ability to query the clipboard sequence number, and **Windows Vista added support for clipboard format listeners**. Clipboard viewer windows are supported for backward compatibility with earlier versions of Windows. **New programs should use clipboard format listeners** or the clipboard sequence number.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dataxchg_Monitoring_Clipboard_Contents):

> A clipboard viewer window displays the current content of the clipboard, and receives 
>   messages when the clipboard content changes. To create a clipboard
>   viewer window, your application must do the following:
>
> ```
> Add the window to the clipboard viewer chain.
> Process the WM_CHANGECBCHAIN message.
> Process the WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD message.
> Remove the window from the clipboard viewer chain before it is destroyed.
> ```

Adding a Window to the Clipboard Viewer Chain:

```
case WM_CREATE: 

    // Add the window to the clipboard viewer chain. 

    hwndNextViewer = SetClipboardViewer(hwnd); 
    break;
```

Processing the WM_CHANGECBCHAIN Message:

```
case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN: 

    // If the next window is closing, repair the chain. 

    if ((HWND) wParam == hwndNextViewer) 
        hwndNextViewer = (HWND) lParam; 

    // Otherwise, pass the message to the next link. 

    else if (hwndNextViewer != NULL) 
        SendMessage(hwndNextViewer, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 

    break;
```

Comment: From the same page: "New programs should use clipboard format listeners or the clipboard sequence number." Use AddClipboardFormatListener.

Comment: Correct, that is the third way but the first one is a clipboard viewer: "The oldest method is to create a clipboard viewer window.". The OP has the choice :)

Comment: Clipboard viewers are not recommended on new programs. A misbehaving clipboard viewer can make the clipboard unusable. If there are two clipboard viewers and one misbehaves, the other clipboard viewer will not receive notifications. Clipboard format listeners are more robust.

Comment: And how can I do it in the background without creating windows?

Comment: @user2197224: you cannot, a window is required. But you can create a hidden window in a worker thread, if you don't want to create a window in your main thread.

Comment: @RaymondChen  I have the same question and I am not understanding how to do that.I checked the `msdn` page but I am not getting how to do it in c++,Would you please tell me,how can i make my own clipboard viewer window.

Comment: @krpra See the other answer.