# Reading windows clipboard while loop in c++

Tags: c++, windows, clipboard

Would this be possible? I want to create an application that constantly reads the clipboard for changes, thats why im thinking about using a while loop, and if reads a link for instance, the program would do a specific task.

Im unsure of the code that is used when accessing the clipboard and reading the text as a string. Could anyone explain the code with comments?

Comment: @KenWhite: That's definitely the approach that should be taken instead of busy-polling, but OP seems to be having problems with just reading the clipboard once.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I agree, which is why I voted to close as a dupe of the same post you did. The extra link I provided was to guide the poster to the proper solution.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah. It's in the Linked list over there --->>>. When a golden hammer does a dupe close, it does tend to nuke the others. The link was to [How to track clipboard changes in the background using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25570276/62576)

Comment: @KenWhite: I do know about the "Linked" list, but I'm not sure new users always notice it.  Also it's not entirely clear to me how permanent it is, or whether a link in a deleted comment will drop off the list during some periodic reindexing operation.